# Facebook call to action ios app link

Tags: ios, facebook

When trying to use Call To Action button into facebook to add "Use Application" button on my page, it asks for my ios app link but I don't know what to fill there. I've tried many things without success :

- myAppName://
- myBundleId://
- myStoreId://

Do you know how to build that app link please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook documentation on App Links should help you with your problem:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks

Basically you need to setup a URL that has `<meta>` HTML content which Facebook uses to identify your app and deep link to it. You will need to configure for deep linking in your app too.